# Creating lines indicating the shortest distance points to line in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, point, line, distance, closest-distance

How can I create lines indicating the shortest distance from a points dataset to a to line, avoiding the line to points tool first?

In the past (at another company) we used MapInfo "Distance Calculator". It allows you to calculate distances from different object types (line/point/area) or a selection of a layer to another.

Is there anything similar yet in QGIS 3.22 available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin for QGIS called [Networks](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/networks/) and a function in it "Connect nodes to lines" does what you need. The plugin is accessible in the Processing Toolbox after its installation.

There is even a better one available in [MMQGIS](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/) (plugin install) called [Hub Lines/Distance](https://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/).